# Sort all List properties (and subproperties) of an object

Tags: vb.net, sorting, reflection

I'm trying to sort all of the List properties of an object (using OrderBy). It's a complex object that has Lists that may contain Lists. I figured that reflection and recursion would get me there, but I seem to be stumbling on actually sorting the lists.

Here is the code I have:

```
Private Sub SortData(ByRef obj As Object)
    Dim type As Type = obj.GetType()
    Dim properties As PropertyInfo() = type.GetProperties()

    For Each item As PropertyInfo In properties
        If Not item.PropertyType.FullName.Contains("System.Collection") AndAlso item.PropertyType.FullName.Contains("MyType") Then
            Dim value = obj.GetType().GetProperty(item.Name).GetValue(obj)
            If value IsNot Nothing Then
                SortData(value)
            End If
        End If

        If item.PropertyType.FullName.Contains("System.Collection") Then
            Dim value = obj.GetType().GetProperty(item.Name).GetValue(obj)
            If value IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim subType As Type = value(0).GetType()
                Dim subProperties As PropertyInfo() = subType.GetProperties()
                If subProperties.Any(Function(x) x.Name = "SortKey") Then
                    ' --- Struggling here! ---
                    Dim castList = TryCast(value, List(Of MoreDetail))
                    value = castList.OrderBy(Function(x) x.SortKey)
                    value = TryCast(value, List(Of MoreDetail))
                    ' --- End struggle ---
                End If

                For Each subProperty In subProperties
                    SortData(value.GetType().GetProperty(subProperty.Name).GetValue(value))
                Next
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

The main problem is in the "struggling here" section of the code - I seem to have to cast the object into its original type, but that defeats the purpose of the reflection as different objects will have a different list type, so ideally I'd be able to cast the object based on its reflected type.

Thanks for the help!

EDIT: To alleviate the "XY problem" in my question, here's what I'm trying to do... I want to be able to sort all List properties of an object - the problem is that the object can have nested lists, so ideally I'd do this via reflection, recursively checking to see if a list contains a list in any of the child properties. The lists are mostly complex types, so I want to sort a list only if the collection contains objects that have the "SortKey" property defined.

EDIT 2: An example of what I'm after is something like (pseudocode):

```
Public Class SuperList
    Public Property A As String = ""
    Public Property BList As New List(Of B)
End Class

Public Class B
   Public Property SortKey As String = ""
   Public Property Name As String = ""
   Public Property CList As New List(Of C)
End Class

Public Class C
   Public Property SortKey As String = ""
   Public Property Name As String = ""
End Class

Dim cExampleSecond As New C With {.SortKey = "345", .Name = "C Second"}
Dim cExampleFirst As New C With {.SortKey = "123", .Name = "C First"}
Dim BExampleFirst As New B With {.Sortkey = "ABC", .Name = "B First"}
BExampleFirst.CList.Add(cExampleSecond)
BExampleFirst.CList.Add(cExampleFirst)
Dim superExample As New SuperList With {.A = "Whatever"}
superExample.BList.Add(BExampleFirst)

...
SortData(superExample)
...
```

After running SortData() it should look like:

```
superExample = 
   .A = "Whatever"
   .BList = 
      .SortKey = "ABC"
      .BExampleFirst = 
         cExampleFirst = 
            .SortKey = "123" 
            .Name = "C First"
         cExampleSecond = 
            .SortKey = "345" 
            .Name = "C Second"
```

Note that if superExample.BList had more elements, they would also be sorted...

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Give example of inputs & outputs you wish to get.

Comment: @Plutonix thanks - I've edited the question a little more (at the bottom) to give an idea of what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: @Han ok I'll put that in an edit

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your example, I would consider that you want to sort a kind of tree.

1- Tree means recursivity: the SortData() will sort the current level/current list, and call SortData() for every sub-element. You can use  inheritance or composition to implement this functionality in every element of your tree.

2- You can use the `sort` functionality of the `List` and `Dictionary`. You only have to implement the IComparable for the element of you list.

Here is some sample code that illustrates the global method.

```
Public Class SortedElem

    Implements IComparable(Of SortedElem)
    Public Property Children As New List(Of SortedElem)
    Public Property SortKey As String

    Public Sub SortData()
        Children.Sort()
        For Each child In Children
            child.Children.Sort()
        Next
    End Sub

    Public Function CompareTo(other As SortedElem) As Integer Implements IComparable(Of SortedElem).CompareTo
        Return String.Compare(Me.SortKey, other.SortKey)
    End Function

End Class

Public Class SuperList
    Inherits SortedElem
    Public Property A As String = ""
End Class

Public Class B
    Inherits SortedElem
    Public Property Name As String = ""

End Class

Public Class C
    Inherits SortedElem
    Public Property Name As String = ""
End Class

Public Sub AnySub()

    Dim cExampleFirst As New C With {.SortKey = "1", .Name = "C First"}
    Dim cExampleSecond As New C With {.SortKey = "3", .Name = "C Second"}
    Dim cExampleThird As New C With {.SortKey = "2", .Name = "C Third"}

    Dim BExampleFirst As New B With {.SortKey = "ABC", .Name = "B First"}
    Dim BExampleSecond As New B With {.SortKey = "XYZ", .Name = "B Second"}
    Dim BExampleThird As New B With {.SortKey = "DEF", .Name = "B Third"}

    BExampleFirst.Children.Add(cExampleFirst)
    BExampleFirst.Children.Add(cExampleSecond)
    BExampleFirst.Children.Add(cExampleThird)

    Dim superExample As New SuperList With {.A = "Whatever"}
    superExample.Children.Add(BExampleFirst)
    superExample.Children.Add(BExampleSecond)
    superExample.Children.Add(BExampleThird)

    superExample.SortData()

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks - this looks like an option, but this will require a lot of changes to the class so they all inherit from that main class. This might not be the best solution in my case, but I'll have a go at it someday soon!